# Trying to save a nested object to my REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

REST/API newbie here!

I want to save a list of things to a user, but I am not getting the desired response.

My mongoose schema looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  mongooseSchema = mongoose.Schema,
  userSchema = {
    "name": String,
    "email": String,
    "cookies": {
      "cookie": [{
        "name": String,
        "brand": String
      }]
    }
  };
```

And (the messed up part of) my user route looks like this:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.cookies = {
      "cookie": [{
        "name": req.body.cookies.cookie.name,
        "brand": req.body.cookies.cookie.brand
    }]
};
```

My response ends up being:

```
{
  "_id": "56048e38701a663707b49c7a",
  "__v": 0,
  "email": "netopwibby@thenetwork.email",
  "name": "NetOperator Wibby",
  "cookies": {
    "cookie": []
  }
}
```

I've been trying to get an API up and running for the past week and while inching further to success, am still not there yet. If anyone can shed some light onto why my code isn't working, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: I updated my user update function to apply @ianaya89's code and still, no luck. Posted that function here in full.

```
function updateUser(req, res) {
  var updatedUser = {};
  updatedUser.name = req.body.name;
  updatedUser.email = req.body.email;
  updatedUser.cookies = {
    "cookie": [{
      "name": req.body.cookies.cookie.name
      "brand": req.body.cookies.cookie.brand
    }]
  };

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updatedUser, {new: true})
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          "ERROR": err
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          "UPDATED": user
        });
      }
      //... your callback
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to find one record based on passed id right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code works ok but `mongoose` is returning the old user properties instead the new ones. So you can try with `findByIdAndUpdate` method and an approach like this:

```
var updatedUser = {};
updatedUser.name = req.body.name;
updatedUser.email = req.body.email;
updatedUser.cookies = {
  "cookie": [{
  "name": req.body.cookies.cookie.name,
  "brand": req.body.cookies.cookie.brand
}];

User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updatedUser, {new: true})
  .exec(function(err, user){
    //... your callback  
  });
```

The third parameter of `findByIdAndUpdate` is a set of possible options, in this case I am setting it to return the updated user instead the old one: `{new: true}`.

Check out the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).

Comment: Hey man, I tried applying your code to my function and still didn't get the desired result. I have updated my original post to include my entire user update function.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby are you getting correctly req.body.cookies? I mean if your function get the desired values before update the user

Comment: Is there a way for me to check that, before updating?

Comment: You can debug your app using node-inspector or even more easy use console.log to print the object values

Comment: I'm not sure how to see the response from a `console.log` and this update function. I am using Postman to test my API. I just know that I see an empty domains area.

Comment: Just do somethink like this `console.log(req.body)`, before calling `findByIdAndUpdate`. Then take a look at the terminal where you are running the node app. 

Another thing you can do to test it inside postman is comment the `findByIdAndUpdate` method and send the `req.body` as response: `res.json(req.body)`